# Can Prism regions be made draggable?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, prism

how do I make the bounds of Prism regions draggable?

As of now the bounds are assigned in xaml.

how do I accomplish this?

Comment: What type of control are you using, how do you want it to be draggable?

Comment: It was a content control . I accomplished this by using Avalon dock and hosting a region within each document panel. That was the only way of doing this i presume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosted a region within Avalon docks document panel.